# Real Analysis Question: Suppose $A\subset B\subset \mathbb R$. Prove that if $B$ is countable then $A$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A\subset B\subset\mathbb R$. Prove that if $B$ is countable then $A$ is countable.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

If $A=\emptyset$, then there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, let $f:\Bbb N\to B$ be surjective and let $w\in A$. Then, $$g:\Bbb N\to A\\ g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if }f(x)\in A\\ w&\text{if }f(x)\notin A\end{cases}$$
is surjective as well.

Comment: why is it from N to B and not from R to B?

Comment: @Jenny Because you said "countable".